# Php checkbox POST array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a html contact form that has checkboxes.  When I go to get the $_POST data all I see for the checkbox field is ARRAY.

Here is the checkbox snippet form the HTML form

```
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="check 1">Type 1
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="check 2 ">Type 2
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="check 3">Type 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="check 4">Type 4
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is my PHP processing file

```
$email = $_POST['email'];

if ( is_array ( $_POST['services'] ) ) {
    $services = $_POST['services'];
}

echo 'email is: ' . $email . ' services :' . $services;
```

Email works fine as its just POST data from one input field.  But how do I save the array into a variable so it does something like

```
$services = "check 1, check 2, check 3";
```

Comment: `$_POST['services']` is an array. So you can call each array elements value like `$_POST['services'][0]`, `$_POST['services'][1]` etc. The easiest way would be to use a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to just put that array in your email. In that case `PHP` will use just word `Array` to let you know it's actual array, not a string.

To get comma-separated list you should use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) function on `$services` (don't forget to filter it first!).

```
$commaList = implode(', ', $services);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `implode()` function in PHP.

```
$variable = implode(', ', $services);
```

You could also use a foreach loop.

```
$variable = '';
foreach($services as $key => $value){
    $variable .= $value . ', ';
}

rtrim($variable, ', ');
```